# Where is the current react-navigation-stack repository?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, npm, react-navigation-stack

If I go to the `react-navigation-stack` npm page at [react-navigation-stack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-stack/v/2.10.2?spm=a2c6h.14275010.0.0.2036f405yN7MOa&file=2.10.2) and click on the [Homepage](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation-stack#readme) it takes me to a read-only repository which tells me the package has been moved to [@react-navigation/stack](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/main/packages/stack) but this page contains the `@react-navigation/stack` package.  Also the `react-navigation-stack` npm page at [react-navigation-stack](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-navigation-stack/v/2.10.2?spm=a2c6h.14275010.0.0.2036f405yN7MOa&file=2.10.2) says documentation can be found on the [React Navigation website](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) but this site says nothing about `react-navigation-stack` and instead says to install `@react-navigation/stack`. `@react-navigation/stack` is listed as a dev dependency for `react-navigation-stack` and I wanted to see what version of `@react-navigation/stack` was being used by `react-navigation-stack` but the last version of `react-navigation-stack` I could find code for was 2.1.1 and the current version is 2.10.2.

Comment: currently i m using "^5.7.1" and it is working fine.

Comment: We have an issue with testId not showing up on individual elements displayed in a flat list. The issue started when we updated from 1.10.3 to 2.1.1. So it only effects our appium tests. I will put the details in a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

It's in the 4.x branch of the main repo: https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation/tree/4.x/packages/stack

Documentation also has a version drop down for 4.x

[image]